# Javascript merge to array with some identical value at certain index

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I have 2 arrays which i want to combine (merge), but if value at index 0 from first array  is identical with value at index 0 on second array this must be in the same array.
More details:
Array 1:

```
var arr1 = [
    ["SP.22110000295", 1,      162.9],
    ["SP29372",        1,     1061.6],
    ["SP3204200014",   5,     1147.5],
    ["SP324035",       1, 94110.0231]
];
```

Array 2:

```
 var arr2  [
    ["999974",           1],
    ["SP.SAMBACR803805", 1],
    ["SP29193",          1],
    ["SP29372",          4],
    ["SP324035",         3]
]
```

As you can see (in this example), first array have another 4 array with 3 items, and second 5 array with 2 items.
arr1[3][0] ([**"SP324035"**, 1, 94110.0231]) is equal with arr2[4][0] ([**"SP324035"**, 1])

so i don't know hot achieve a result like this:

```
var arrfinal = [
   ["SP.22110000295",     1,      162.9, null], // arr1 index 0 **is not** in arr2 index 0
   ["SP29372",            1,     1061.6,    4], // arr1 index 0 **is** in arr2 index 0
   ["SP3204200014",       5,     1147.5, null], // arr1 index 0 **is not** in arr2 index 0
   ["SP324035",           1, 94110.0231,    3], // arr1 index 0 **is** in arr2 index 0
   ["999974",          null,       null,    1], // arr2 index 0 **is not** in arr1 index 0
   ["SP.SAMBACR803805",null,       null,    1], // arr2 index 0 **is not** in arr1 index 0
   ["SP29193",         null,       null,    1]  // arr2 index 0 **is not** in arr1 index 0
];
```

Actualy it's not realy a merge, because just arrays where values of index 0 are equals are merged others it's kind of splice.

I tried with merge, expand splice... underscore, jquery...

Any hints please?

Thank you, very much,
Geo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question is you have two *Arrays*, `arr1` and `arr2`, and you want to generate a new *Array*, `arrfinal`, with the folowing conditions

1. Items from `arr1` should be copied to `arrfinal`
2. If there exists an `arrfinal[i][0] === arr2[j][0]` for some *i, j*, then items of `arr[2][j]` from index `1` should be appened to the end of the items from `arr1[i]` in `arrfinal`
3. If this does not happen, push a new *Array* to `arrfinal` with index `0` of `arr2[j][0]` padded by `null`s before appending the other items from `arr2[j]`
4. All items in `arrfinal` should have the same *length*

```js
var arrfinal = [],
    key_map = {},
    max_len_1 = 0,
    max_len_2 = 0,
    i, j;

for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
    max_len_1 = Math.max(max_len_1, arr1[i].length); // find maximum length of arr1
    arrfinal.push(arr1[i].slice()); // copy to final
    key_map[arr1[i][0]] = arrfinal.length - 1; // mapping for later
}

for (i = 0; i < arrfinal.length; ++i) { // fix lengths
    while (arrfinal[i].length < max_len_1) {
        arrfinal[i].push(null);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; ++i) {
    max_len_2 = Math.max(max_len_2, arr2[i].length); // find maximum length of arr2
    if (key_map.hasOwnProperty(arr2[i][0])) { // entry exists from arr1
        j = key_map[arr2[i][0]];
    } else { // generate a new entry
        j = arrfinal.push([arr2[i][0]]) - 1;
        while (arrfinal[j].length < max_len_1) { // fix length
            arrfinal[j].push(null);
        }
    }
    Array.prototype.push.apply(
        arrfinal[j],
        arr2[i].slice(1)
    );
}

for (i = 0; i < arrfinal.length; ++i) { // fix lengths one last time
    while (arrfinal[i].length < max_len_1 + max_len_2 - 1) {
        arrfinal[i].push(null);
    }
}
```

---

It should be noted however, that this may give unexpected results if there exists *multiple* items which have the same value at index `0` per `arr1` or `arr2`, for example

```
var arr1 = [
    [ 'foo',      1],
    ['fizz', 'buzz']
];
var arr2 = [
    ['foo', 'bar']
    ['foo', 'baz']
];
```

would result in

```
[
    [ 'foo',      1, 'bar', 'baz'],
    ['fizz', 'buzz',  null       ]
]
```

Further, if these are guaranteed to be unique then perhaps you should consider using an *Object* instead of an *Array*

Comment: Thank you very much. it's works. meanwhile i found another aprouch with same result. thank you.